# AngularJS Post to controller and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to redirect to another View `SecondView()` after post request from angularjs. I know that angular have somethig like `$location.path`. But i want to check some conditions in controller.

JavaScript

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
MyApp.controller("AppController", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.onClick = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/CheckData/',
            data: {name: 'Jhon'},
        });
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckData(string name)
    {
        if (name=="Jhon")
        {
        return RedirectToAction("SecondView");}
        else{
            return View();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult SecondView()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppController">
    <input ng-click="onClick()" type="button" value="Redirect" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use response callback to check your conditions and do what is needed there:

```
$scope.onClick = function() {
  $http.post('Home/CheckData/', { name: 'Jhon'}).then(function(resp) {
    if (resp.data.someVar) {
      // javascript redirect using `$location`
    } else {
      // set some scope variable to display error
    }
  });
};
```

You will need to return appropriate JSON from server to do the conditional check

Question is a bit vague to be able to provide more detail

Answer (score -1):

No, if you're making an AJAX request, you will not be able to have your server-side controller redirect you, since the client is responsible for navigation in the context you explained. I would suggest either checking some something in your JSON response from the server (myObject.shouldRedirect = true, or a URL, for that matter), or check for a particular HTTP response code (200 vs something else) and then do the redirection from the Angular controller.

If you want it to be async using thr Angular API, then yes, `$location.path` is by far the way to go. If you actually need to go for something that doesn't implement the History API (i.e., you need the more tradition server-side redirection), you can always go for `window.location = 'xyz'`.

Comment: Actually the server should always respond to the client so why not parse that response into something meaningful (url redirect for example?) check @charlietfl 's answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both answers are getting to the same point: Have the server respond with some kind of payload, then based on it, redirect or do something else. (For clarification purposes, I just added the word Angular when referring to which controller should handle the redirect — things tend to get ambiguous when you're talking about Web API and Angular in the same sentence.)